# Is there any maven sleep functionality?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I have maven profile set for testing where in pre-integration-tests maven starts two jetty servers and afterwards tests are started. The problem I've stumbled into is in the servers, they aren't fully loaded when tests start. It seems like the problem is fixed by adding 5 second sleep time into the tests, but I wish to add it in maven and remove from tests. Is there anyway I could do that? Please look into code sample below for additional information

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.work.projectname</groupId>
                                <artifactId>projectname-web</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <destFileName>projectname-${project.version}.war</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.work.projectname</groupId>
                                <artifactId>projectname-stubs-web</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <destFileName>projectname-stubs-${project.version}.war</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-server.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-projectname</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                        <reload>manual</reload>
                        <war>${project.build.directory}/projectname-${project.version}.war</war>
                        <webAppXml>${basedir}/src/jetty/jetty-loginService.xml</webAppXml>
                        <webAppConfig>
                            <contextPath>/projectname</contextPath>
                            <parentLoaderPriority>true</parentLoaderPriority>
                            <tempDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp-projectname</tempDirectory>
                        </webAppConfig>
                        <stopPort>8006</stopPort>
                        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-projectname-stubs</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                        <reload>manual</reload>
                        <war>${project.build.directory}/projectname-stubs-${project.version}.war</war>
                        <connectors>
                            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                                <port>${stub-jetty-server.port}</port>
                                <maxIdleTime>300000</maxIdleTime>
                            </connector>
                        </connectors>
                        <stopPort>8008</stopPort>
                        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-projectname</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <stopPort>8006</stopPort>
                        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-projectname-stubs</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <stopPort>8008</stopPort>
                        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCountClasses>33</threadCountClasses>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it with the help of the maven antrun plugin. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <tasks>
            <sleep seconds="5" />
        </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sleep-for-a-while</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

EDIT: In case someone will catch this. Based on the comment from jl, tasks have indeed been deprecated and here is the same thing based on using targets instead. Sligthly reorganized but has the same function.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sleep-for-a-while</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <sleep seconds="5" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, would you kindly explain how this could be launched before interation-tests. I've tried setting phase to pre-integration-tests but this didn't work for me. Maven goals which are being used are clean verify

Comment: I have added an example. In what way didn't it work for you? I hope you are using pre-integration-test as a phase (note that you have pre-integration-tests but that may be a typo?).

Comment: @Keynash : Put it somewhere after the definition of the jetty-maven-plugin. This will slow down the build by five seconds, before the stage of the integration tests is reached, thus allowing enough time for Jetty to start.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me, after I've started using `clean install` instead of `clean verify`

Comment: seems like the `tasks` tag is deprecated (since maven-antrun-plugin 1.5?) and `target` should be used instead. [more info](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [maven-sleep-plugin](https://github.com/OndraZizka/maven-sleep-plugin) once. Not sure how much it works now, you can try and let us know.

Usage (after checking out the source and building):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-sleep-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sleep-5-seconds</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sleep</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                 <delay>5</delay>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```