# How to make maven execution sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, build, jvm

The scenario is this. Our project consist of multiple modules, and purpose of one specific module is to halt the execution of maven for certain period of time before building next module. The sleep time have been defined as JVM property in previous module by calling `System.setProperty` in the java application ran by *exec-maven-plugin*.

My initial idea was to run java program which calls `Thread.sleep` in this module, but it doesn't seem to affect maven execution. I guess *exec-maven-plugin* runs the program in separate thread.

How do I halt the maven execution for the period of time, which is provided as JVM argument?

Comment: It's ugly, but you could include a ``Thread.sleep`` in the unit tests. I repeat: it's ugly. And I wouldn't do it.

Comment: `exec:exec` executes in a separated process while `exec:java` in the same JVM, which goal of the `exec-maven-plugin` are you using?

Comment: I'm using exec:java

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found:

Instead of Java class, I use *maven-antrun-plugin* to halt the execution inside module

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wait</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <sleep seconds="${duration}" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Here is the original thread
[Is there any maven sleep functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701229/is-there-any-maven-sleep-functionality)